# Regular expression doesn't work in Go

Tags: regex, go

forgive me for being a regex amateur but I'm really confused as to why this doesn't piece of code doesn't work in Go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var a string = "parameter=0xFF"
    var regex string = "^.+=\b0x[A-F][A-F]\b$"
    result,err := regexp.MatchString(regex, a)
    fmt.Println(result, err)
}
// output: false <nil>
```

This seems to work OK in python

```
import re

p = re.compile(r"^.+=\b0x[A-F][A-F]\b$")
m = p.match("parameter=0xFF")
if m is not None:
    print m.group()

// output: parameter=0xFF
```

All I want to do is match whether the input is in the format `<anything>=0x[A-F][A-F]`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using raw string literal (with back quote instead of quote)?
Like this:

```
var regex string = `^.+=\b0x[A-F][A-F]\b$`
```

Comment: Ah yes, this worked too. I'm going to keep this trick mind when writing regular expressions in Go.

Answer (score 5):

You must escape the `\` in [interpreted literal strings](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) :

```
var regex string = "^.+=\\b0x[A-F][A-F]\\b$"
```

But in fact the `\b` (word boundaries) appear to be useless in your expression.

It works without them :

```
var regex string = "^.+=0x[A-F][A-F]$"
```

[Demonstration](http://play.golang.org/p/ePNmOdigZf)

Comment: To be fair... I'm not sure about why it doesn't work with the `\b`. It seems it would work with a compiled regex.

Comment: `\b` is an escape character that means backspace. For instance, this code `fmt.Println("12\b3")` prints `13`. It is why you need to use the raw string literal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183704/regular-expression-doesnt-work-in-go/14183804#answer-14183804

Comment: Ok, that explains it. More generally (when the word boundary is needed), we must escape the \ in literal strings. Thanks (and +1 on your answer).